# Make textbox default value equals to 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, text, default-value

I have set my textbox = 0

```
<p>Credit Balance: </p><asp:TextBox ID="txtCredit" runat="server" style="width:70px" Text = "0"></asp:TextBox>
```

and my code behind is this:

```
scn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CreditRequest FROM UserData WHERE Username=@Username", scn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["New"];

object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (value != null)
{
    txtCredit.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(value).ToString("#,##0.00");
}
```

What i want to happen is if it has value, it will display it. if none, default value is equal to 0. But i am receiving an error

```
Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
```

Comment: You can set your column to Not NULL and set default value for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect, value is coming as `DBNull`, you could guard against `DBNull` using  `Convert.IsDBNull` method.

```
if (!Convert.IsDBNull(value))
{
    txtCredit.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(value).ToString("#,##0.00");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using null, use DBNull.

```
if(value != DBNull)
{
// update textbox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Things you should consider:

- Instead of setting the text attribute, sent its VALUE.
- Verify your value before converting it. You are comparing it from null, but it is a DBNull. Check this information in addition to your Null validation.

Good luck!